# Singular they and each - is it ambiguous?

Tags: singular-they

*CONTEXT: a card game involving more than 2 players. Each player can do multiple things during their turn (including picking a card).*

Considering the following sentence:

> During each player's turn, they pick a card from their deck.

Can it be understood as:

> 1. During each player's turn, *each of them* picks a card from their respective deck

Or is it clear that only the player whose turn it is picks a card ?

Original sentence was:

> During each player's turn, he or she picks a card from his or her deck.

If there is an ambiguity, is there an elegant way to rephrase the sentence to remove that ambiguity?

EDIT: For instance, would it be clearer rephrased the other way round?

> 2. Each player picks a card from their deck during their turn.

or

> 3. During their turn, each player picks up a card from their deck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic case of trying to avoid both the clumsiness of repeated **he's** and **she's**, and of getting around the gender-neutral singular **they**.

Your example sentence is not ambiguous and makes the best compromise, using the singular *they* and *their*.

You could say:

> Each player in turn picks a card from that player's deck

which avoids the singular *they* that some speakers dislike
although many people would doubt that it's any improvement.

Or you can accept the laboured construction of the original sentence.

If there's a simple manner of rephrasing the sentence to please all parties,
I'm not aware of it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wanted to be sure it's not ambiguous. I should have added a context to my original question because the turn of a player is not restricted to picking a card (they can do other stuff), so players won't be picking a card in turn.